# C++ insertion operator for class method

Tags: c++, iostream, ostream, insertion

In C++ is there a way to use the insertion operator for a class method?

This `operator<<` overload is working:

```
class Complex {
public:
  //Normal overload:
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Complex &o) {
    out << "test overload";
    return out;
  }

  Complex() {};
  ~Complex() {};
};
```

I can do this:

```
int main()
{
  Complex* o = new Complex();

  std::cout << "This is test: " << *o << "." << std::endl; // => This is test: test overload.
}
```

I know about stream manipulators, like this:

```
std::ostream& welcome(std::ostream& out)
{
    int data = 1;
    out << "WELCOME " << data << "\r\n";
    return out;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello " << welcome; // => "Hello WELCOME 1\r\n"
}
```

How can I put the `welcome` method into the `Complex` class and then how shall I call it from `cout` (please note that welcome method must access some class member variables)?

My trial:

```
class Complex {
public:
  //Normal overload:
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Complex &o) {
    out << "test overload";
    return out;
  }

  std::ostream& welcome(std::ostream& out) {
    out << "WELCOME " << data << "\r\n";
    return out;
  }

  Complex() { data = 1; };
  ~Complex() {};
private:
  int data;
};

int main()
{
  Complex* o = new Complex();

  std::cout << "This is test2: " << o->welcome << std::endl; // compile error
}
```

Comment: Please show real code. Your "normal" overload is a member function and cannot work like this

Comment: `mymethod` could return a string then you can do `std::cout << c.mymethod() << " then other stuff"`. Please clarify, its not really clear what your problem is

Comment: What exactly would be the intended output of your program?

Comment: You could write a custom manipulator to achieve such an effect. https://accu.org/index.php/journals/1769

Comment: I think I've answered all the questions in the update. @idclev463035818: returning a string is not good, because the method shall also utilize the stream and insert more items.

Comment: Yes, for the initial I wrote from head. Sorry for that. I left there for historic reasons.

Comment: you do not have to leave it there for history, you also do not have to add "UPDATE" to your question. If someone wants to see the edit history, they can do so here: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62072866/revisions

Comment: there can be arguments against returning a string from the method but I do not understand yours. You can get the desired output when `extrainfo` returns a string

Comment: your example was better before. Now the welcome method does nothing but pipe a single string into the stream. Anyhow, hope the answer helps. Will add some more on why yours doesnt work

Comment: @idclev463035818: extrainfo will concat a lot of components with <<. That's why I'd like to keep the stream-based approach.

Comment: btw I suggest you to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500313/why-should-c-programmers-minimize-use-of-new There is no reason to use `new` in your code and you are leaking memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way to pick a different `<<` overload is to use a different type.

```
#include <iostream>

class Complex {
public:
  //Normal overload:
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Complex &o) {
    out << "test overload";
    return out;
  }

  struct extra_info {
      const Complex& parent;
      extra_info(const Complex& p) : parent(p) {}
      friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const extra_info& ei){
        int i = 1;
        out << "extrainfo " << i;
        return out;
      }
  };
  extra_info extrainfo() {
      return {*this};
  }

  Complex() {};
  ~Complex() {};
};


int main() {
    Complex c;
    std::cout << c << "\n";
    std::cout << c.extrainfo();
}
```

Output:

```
test overload
extrainfo 1
```

I suppose in your real code you are using members. Hence the helper type must hold a reference to the `Complex` instance.

Comment: hmm.. could we  get rid of warning by using non-recursive manipulator? Not like we need an argument in case of nested class. Or one can remove name of `ei` argument

Comment: `c.welcome(std::cout)` fails compiling on my machine: "error: cannot bind ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}’ lvalue to ‘std::basic_ostream&&’"

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie sorry I dont understand. I get no warning and there is no recursion

Comment: @Daniel sorry you changed the code to quickly and I got lazy do write the answer carefully, my fault, I will just remove it

Comment: @idclev463035818: I'm interested in your oppinion: this extrainfo solution is theoretically better (faster to run) than creating a stringstream and returning it for cout?

Comment: @Daniel I dont understand what you mean. It is less expensive than constructing a string and printing that. Not sure, but the compiler will likely optimize the `extra_info` away. If you care about performance you need to look at the output of the compiler, but don't do premature optimization, code is primarily written to be read by humans and you should write code to be readable

Comment: @Daniel btw never listen to "opinions" about performance. Compiler optimizations are an extremely involved process and naive expectations are too often completely off.

Comment: Thx. Is there any way to use private members of *Compex* class when constructing extrainfo?

Comment: @Daniel you can make `extra_info` a friend of `Complex`. Dont remember atm, maybe nested classes already have access to privates, but I might be completely wrong